# How to print ordered submodel in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have models:

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...
    pos = models.IntegerField(...

class Model_2(models.Model):
    ...
    m1 = models.ManyToManyField(Model_1,...
```

and I print this in template:

```
{% for m2 in model2 %}
    {% for m1 in m2.m1.all %}
        {{ m1.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I want to print m1.names ordered by 'pos' field. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the model you can specify ordering of the objects. More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)

```
class M1():
   ...
   class Meta:
      ordering = ['pos']
```